# Element shouldn't be fading but is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just like the title says, I have an element that shouldn't be fading but is. The element in question is text on top of an image that fades when you move your mouse over it.

HTML:

```
<div id="image-wrapper">
<ul id="team-members">
    <li class="tile-wrapper fade">
        <div class="tile">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/158x210" />
             <h3 class="bio bio-header" style="display:none;">Header</h3>
            <p class="bio bio-footer" style="display:none;">Information</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.fade').mouseenter(function (ev) {
    $(this).fadeTo(150, 0.5);
    $(this).find('img').siblings().fadeIn(150);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(150, 1);
    $(this).find('img').siblings().fadeOut(150);
});
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLckb6h3/4/

Comment: Image is not fading, `$(this).fadeTo(150, 0.5);` line fading the whole `.fade` and you're thinking that image is fading. Just comment the line and check.

Comment: @thecodeparadox how do you suggest I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion:

**HTML**

```
<div id="image-wrapper" >
    <ul id="team-members">
        <li class="tile-wrapper fade">
            <div class="tile">
                <div class="doFade">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3 class="bio bio-header">Header</h3>
                    <p class="bio bio-footer">Information</p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/158x210"/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.bio {
    padding:15px;
}

.tile {
    width:158px;
    height:210px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.doFade {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: none;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fade').mouseenter(function(ev) {
        $('.doFade', this).add( $('.info', this) ).fadeIn(150);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $('.doFade', this).add( $('.info', this) ).fadeOut(150);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oLckb6h3/12/)

Comment: When I ran the demo, the text was still faded

Answer (score 0):

Fade the `img` rather than the `.fade` element...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fade').mouseenter(function(ev) {
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo(150, 0.5).siblings().fadeIn(150);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo(150, 1).siblings().fadeOut(150);
    });
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.bio {
    padding:15px;
}

.bio-header {
    margin-top:-150px;
}

.tile {
    width:158px;
    height:210px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="image-wrapper" >
    <ul id="team-members">
        <li class="tile-wrapper fade">
            <div class="tile">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/158x210"/>
                <h3 class="bio bio-header" style="display:none;">Header</h3>
                <p class="bio bio-footer" style="display:none;">Information</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When I ran the demo, the text was still faded